# How can i run this program in parallel

Tags: python

I have this program, i am trying to get test1 and test2 to run concurrently:

```
__author__ = 'user'
import time
class test():
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message=message
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print self.message
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test1 = test("PRINT-1")
    test2 = test("PRINT-2")

    test1.run()
    test2.run()
```

Output:

```
PRINT-1
PRINT-1
PRINT-1
PRINT-1
PRINT-1
PRINT-1
.....
```

The output suggests that test1 is being run and due to the while loop test2 is never run. How can i run test1 and test2 concurrently. I tried using pool and multiprocessing but i am having implementation issues.

Desired output:

```
    PRINT-1
    PRINT-2
    PRINT-1
    PRINT-2
    PRINT-1
    PRINT-2
    .....
```

Comment: you should use `thread`

Comment: here has a good tutorial about it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm